# Как обратиться к документу во фрейме?

Tags: javascript

Как в js обратиться к дочернему документу, который находится во встроенном фрейме (элемент iframe)?

Comment: По моему этого делать нельзя

Answer (score 2):

Обращение к document:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument
```

Обращение к window:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow
```

Учтите, что страницы должны быть на одном домене, порту, и схеме ( протоколе )!